# How to bind an Interface to a Razor form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a Razor form (from scaffolding), the binding is to an Interface:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ImageStorm.DB.Core.ImagestormContext _context;

    public CreateModel(ImageStorm.DB.Core.ImagestormContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public IImaging Imaging { get; set; } = new Imaging();

    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Imagings.Add((Imaging)Imaging);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

I have created an Interface for the EF.Core class so I can put attributes there and not worry about losing them all when updating the model.

```
    public interface IImaging
    {
        string Cron { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MMM-dd HH: mm}")]
        DateTime? CronEnd { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MMM-dd HH: mm}")]
...
```

This works great for the Scafolded Index page.

However when I use this approach for a Create page, I get the following error on Save:

**InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'ImageStorm.DB.Core.IImaging'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, set the 'Imaging' property to a non-null value in the 'ImageStorm.Client.CreateModel' constructor.**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.BindModelCoreAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, int propertyData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, object value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageBinderFactory+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<CreatePropertyBinder>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.BindArgumentsCoreAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Is there a work-around or better approach ?

Comment: The error message is clear **`Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. `**. Use the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> How to bind an Interface to a Razor form

**You don't.**

The error message is clear

> *Model bound complex types **must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor**. `*.

*emphasis mine*

Use the concrete implementation.

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel {
    private readonly ImageStorm.DB.Core.ImagestormContext _context;

    public CreateModel(ImageStorm.DB.Core.ImagestormContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet() {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Imaging Imaging { get; set; } = new Imaging();//<-- NOTE USE OF IMPLEMENTATION 

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Imagings.Add(Imaging);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: If set the various attributes on the EF.Core classes and bind them it works. However, when I update the model, all those edits are lost. Is there a strategy to avoid this ?